# How to iterate rows of dataframe into multi line sentences?

Tags: python, string, pandas, format

I am using twilio to send out alerts.

I need to send out an alert with particular sentences with values from one dataframe appended into the sentences. How would I do this?

Example dataframe looks like this:

```
    zone          script  totalcount           datetimecomplete
0   2.0       Consumers           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
1   2.0       Inventory           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
2   2.0  Orders_Details           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
3   3.0       Consumers           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
4   3.0       Inventory           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
5   3.0  Orders_Details           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
6   6.0        Birthday           1 2018-05-02 17:46:38.232354
```

Multi-line sentences look like this:

```
"""
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
"""
```

For each of the rows of the multi line string, I need the corresponding row of my dataframe populated only for columns `[zone, script,  totalcount]`

Example(Text needs to look like this):

```
 """
    Zone: 2.0, Script: Consumers, 1 Successful Completions
    Zone: 2.0, Script: Inventory, 1 Successful Completions
    Zone: 2.0, Script: Orders_Details, 1 Successful Completions
    Zone: 3.0, Script: Consumers, 1 Successful Completions
    Zone: 3.0, Script: Inventory, 1 Successful Completions
    Zone: 3.0, Script: Orders_Details, 1 Successful Completions
    Zone: 6.0, Script: Birthday, 1 Successful Completions
    """
```

Twilio code so far that is not working:

```
if df.empty == False:
    for i in lst:
        message = client.messages.create(
                to=i, 
                from_="+1234567890",
                body= """
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      Zone: {}, Script: {}, {} Successful Completions
                      """).format(df)
        time.sleep(5)
    print(message.sid)
else:
    print('script has finished')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
('Zone: '+df.zone.astype(str)+', Script: '+df.script+','+df.totalcount.astype(str)+' Successful Completions')
Out[648]: 
0    Zone: 2.0, Script: Consumers,1 Successful Comp...
1    Zone: 2.0, Script: Inventory,1 Successful Comp...
2    Zone: 2.0, Script: Orders_Details,1 Successful...
3    Zone: 3.0, Script: Consumers,1 Successful Comp...
4    Zone: 3.0, Script: Inventory,1 Successful Comp...
5    Zone: 3.0, Script: Orders_Details,1 Successful...
6    Zone: 6.0, Script: Birthday,1 Successful Compl...
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your answer is exactly what I need. However when I implement your line of code into the 'body' variable I get error. `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I have even tried setting your line of code into a variable and inputting the variable into the 'body' variable.

Comment: @RustyShackleford just adding to_string at the end